# Why Sphinx ranking affect result count

Tags: sphinx, ranking

If ranking serve to  influence the "weight"

It would influence sorting.

So why with my ranking, I have  less result than with another ?

Manual say

```
SPH_MATCH_ANY uses SPH_RANK_MATCHANY ranker;
```

and later in manual

```
SPH_RANK_MATCHANY = sum((word_count+(lcs-1)*max_lcs)*user_weight)
```

ref : http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#weighting

So

```
mode=any
```

and

```
mode=extended2;ranker=expr:sum((word_count+(lcs-1)*max_lcs)*user_weight)'
```

would return same results but it doesn't. Why ?

**has "ranking" influence on  matching ?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible with ranking expression

So my solution is to alter search string

```
 $arrWords = explode(' ', $searchString);
 $searchString =  '"'.implode('"|"', $arrWords).'"';
```

Comment: Sphinx only have one 'matching mode' **internally** - extended. When you select other matching modes, eg any, it rewrites the query to emulate that matching mode (using extended syntax) AND sets a particular ranking mode. So if you want to emulate other matching modes yourself, you need to do both actions as well.